# Would LOX+$NO_2$ or LOX+$N_2O_4$ make a good oxidizer mix?

Tags: oxidizer

We know that oxygen is the "king" of oxidizers:

- non-toxic (unlike fluorine)
- cheap
- *only* an oxidizer (potassium nitrate, for example, comes with K and N which aren't what we want)
- no need for catalysis ($H_2O_2$)

But with all that being said, we still have to contain it inside a very cold tank (90K) or a very pressurized one (so very heavy…).

With all that in mind, would it be a good idea to use nitrogen dioxide ($NO_2$) and/or dinitrogen tetroxide($N_2O_4$) to stabilize the $O_2$? (I mean *raising its boiling point.*)
It would reduce the need for cooling machines (not cheap) while letting the mix be a good oxidizer.

EDIT 1 : As Organic Marble pointed out it seems that $N_2O_4$ could replace $NO_2$ in the question. But because $NO_2$ and $N_2O_4$ are always in chemical equilibrium, filling a tank with one of them is, I guess, filling it with both of them ?

And if any of you think of another good oxidizer that would do the trick, feel free to share the idea!

Comment: +Nathan Tuggy Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: Interesting question.  My usual sources make no mention of it being used as rocket oxidizer, although an Air Liquide fact sheet lists it as a use.  It seems to be quite toxic but that hasn't prevented the use of other propellants.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  wikipedia says " it was used in the Titan rockets, to launch Project Gemini, in the maneuvering thrusters of the Space Shuttle, and in unmanned space probes sent to various planets" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide#Uses)

Comment: No, that is nitrogen tetroxide, a different compound. Is that what you are really asking about?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is said in this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide#Structure_and_properties)  that nitrogen tetroxide stay in an "equilibrium mixture" with $NO_2$. So I didn't made the distinction. it's (I think) the same question ... no?

Comment: No. Your question specifically asks about NO2 and only NO2.  If you are interested in other nitrogen compounds - nitrogen tetroxide is a very common rocket propellant - you need to edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sir ! yes Sir ! :D (is it better ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mix LOX with other gases, those gases should be liquid at the temperature of LOX. But NO2 is solid at only -11.2 °C and N2O4 at -11 °C. The turbo pumps might be destroyed by a mixture of a liquid with solids and the valves and injectors for the oxidizer might be blocked. I doubt that a liquid mixture of O2, NO2 and N2O4 would contain more than very little O2.

Comment: I didn't thought it that ...And at the end of the day, using a gas that work with those criteria wouldn't help to carry the mixture I guess... So disappointing !